# Code not working for some Test Case in codewars for Reverse Word Kata

Tags: c++, reverse, testcase

I need to write a function in C++ that accepts a string parameter and reverses each word in the string. All spaces in the string should be retained. It is working for the random test case but not the sample test cases.

Here is the code that I tried writing:

I tried compiling and testing in Codewars but the Test Case for this kata is not working for my code.

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<string.h>
#include<sstream>

std::string reverse_words(std::string str)
{

   std::string temp;
   std::string space=" ";
   std::string s="";
   std::string word="";

  stringstream iss(str);
  while(iss>>word)
  {

   reverse(word.begin(),word.end());
   s=s+word;
   s=s+space;

   }
return s;
}
```

Expected: equal to ehT kciuq nworb xof spmuj revo eht yzal .god

Actual: ehT kciuq nworb xof spmuj revo eht yzal .god

Screenshot of the test case:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a difference between the "Expected" and "Actual" output, assuming `equal to` is not supposed to be part of it. The only problem I can think of is an extra space at the of your output or double-spaces / other whitespaces in your input. Can you please clarify what the problem is? Also you are supposed to `#include<string>`, not `#include<string.h>` which is a different header.

Comment: Actual output is missing : equal to

Comment: And how does the input look like? Does it contain `lauqe ot`? If not, why should `equal to` be in the output going by the problem description?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the test case for your perusal

Comment: No, I don't think that `equal to` is part of the answer. I think the problem is, that you have an extra space after the correct answer. You cannot see the blank space in the image though. Try to figure out, how to avoid putting a space at the end of your output.

Comment: If "a b c" is the input, what should be the output in your opinion? I bet it should be "a b c", but the output of your program would instead be "a b c "; note the blank before the end of quote. That would not be visible in your screenshot, in a text representation it would be visible, that is why pictures are not appreciated here. I am sure this is what uneven_mark also wants to tell you.

Comment: Try to add a "#" at the end of your output, that is of course even more wrong, but you will be able to see the trailing blank of your output.

Comment: How do I make sure the spaces in the original string are maintained in the resulting reversed string? Using stringstream, I am able to perform word-by-word extraction from the string. How do I count the spaces between the words or in the beginning/end of the original string?